# How to retrieve the 'value' of a key belonging to a BeautifulSoup tag's text which is of dictionary type?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Selecting a value from a dictionary type `text` of a tag.

```
>type(all[0])
bs4.element.Tag
```

The output of the `script` tag gives the below output

```
>all[0].find_all("script")[0]
<script data-initial-state="review-info" type="application/json">
{"key1":"val1", :"key2":"val2", "stars":5}
</script>
```

When i extract the text i get None `''`, which doesn't allow me to go further and choose from the dictionary (if that's straightforward, or does that require json module?)

```
>all[0].find_all("script")[0].text
''
```

Anyway, how do i go forward and retrieve "val2" ?

Comment: what is the type of 'all[0].find_all("script")[0]' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
import json
target = all[0].find_all("script")[0]
data = json.loads(target.text)
for k,v in data.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
key1 val1
key2 val2
stars 5
```

To specifically target one item, use:

```
print(data['key2'])
```

Output:

```
val2
```